# all anagrams - recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to understand the following recursive function below to teach myself recursion. My attempt to explain it is below the expected output and the function itself. what am I missing? I'm not seeing the process where you get from 'abc' to 'acb'. my attempt to understand it got me from 'abc' right to 'bac'.

```
    example usage:
        var anagrams = allAnagrams('abc');
        console.log(anagrams); // [ 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba' ]





        var allAnagrams = function(string) {

          var uniqueOutput = {};

          (function anagram(ana, str) {

            // could have also written this as: if(!str)....
            if (str === '') {
              uniqueOutput[ana] = 1;
            }
            //recursive call for the length of the anagram.
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
              anagram(ana + str[i], str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1));
              console.log(ana);
            }
          })('', string);
          console.log(uniqueOutput)
          return Object.keys(uniqueOutput);
        };


 // you are calling the recursive function like this: anagram([anagram=]'', [string=]'abc')
    // so the base case is not met on the first iteration since the string isn't empty
    // first iteration: i = 0
    // anagram('' + 'a' + 'bc' [from str.slice(0 +1)]) ---> resolves to "abc") ---> anagram("abc")
    //second iteration: i = 1. we are still in the original call from line 37.
    // here below, does "ana" stay as '' since we are still inside the initial recursion call?
    //anagram('' + b + a +  c) ---- resolves to "bac" ---> anagram("bac")
    //third and last iteration iteration: i = 2
    //anagram(" " + c + c) ----> anagram("cc") ? not a valid result.
```

My new, correct (I think) explanation:

```
//initial input: anagram("", "abc")
//STEP 1: enter the function --> i = 0 for original string "abc"
  //anagram("" + "a", "bc") ----> anagram("a", "bc")
//STEP 2: loop through the new, modified string, which is now "bc"
    //var i = 0;
    //anagram("a" + "b", "c")---> anagram("ab", "c")
    //anagram("ab" + "c", [nothing here])
      //base case hit, so uniqueOutput["abc"] = 1;
    //var i = 1; --> this applies to the string "bc". the loop gets reset to i = 0 once you have a new string to worth with (like below, with "b")
    //anagram("a" + "c", "b")
    //anagram("ac", "b")
    //anagram("ac" + "b", "" )
      //base case hit, so uniqueOutput["acb"] = 1;  
//STEP 3: increment up on the original string input ("abc") --> so now you are dealing with str[i] === b
  //var i =  1;
  //anagram("" + "b", "a" + "c")
    //anagram("b", "ac")  ---> now we need to loop through "ac"!
      //anagram("b" + "a", "c")
        //anagram("ba", "c") 
          //anagram("bac", "")---> base case hit, uniqueOutput["bac"] = 1;
    //anagram("b", "ac")
      //anagram("b" + "c", "a") ---> anagram("bc", "a")
        //anagram("bca", "") ---> base case hit, uniqueOutput["bca"] = 1;
//STEP 4: increment up on the original string input ("abc") ---> str[i] === c
  //var i = 2;
  //anagram ("" + "c", "ab")---> anagram("c", "ab")
    //now we need to loop through "ab!" c's index stays the same.
    //anagram("c" + "a", "b") ---> anagram("ca", "b")
      //anagram("cab", '')---> uniqueOuput["cab"] = 1;
    //anagram("c" + "b", "a") ---> anagram("cb", "a")
      //anagram("cba", "")----> uniqueOutput["cba"] = 1
```

Comment: you are missing the second iteration of the first call to anagram in the first iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments above:

```
// first iteration: i = 0
// anagram('' + 'a' + 'bc' [from str.slice(0 +1)]) ---> resolves to "abc") --->
```

Actually on `i = 0`, the arguments passed to `anagram` are:

```
anagram('' + 'a', '' + 'bc');
```

which evaluates to:

```
anagram('a', 'bc');
```

Then within that call to `anagram`, we again loop over `str`, which is now just 'bc'. That will result in 2 more calls to `anagram` which will be

```
anagram('a' + 'b', '' + 'c'); // i = 0
anagram('a' + 'c', 'b' + ''); // i = 1
```

which evaluate to:

```
anagram('ab', 'c');
anagram('ac', 'b');
```

And the second one of those calls will result in another call to `anagram` with these arguments:

```
anagram('acb', '');
```

which gets added to `uniqueOutput` as `str` is now empty.

Only after all that has executed will the code return to the outermost call of `anagram` and `i` will increment as per your comment:

```
//second iteration: i = 1. we are still in the original call from line 37.
```

Comment: that really clarifies it. I was thinking iteratively, forgetting that the initial call to anagram will also be evaluated recursively in the same way!

Comment: In the top level call, i will not increment from 0 to 1 until the 'abc' and 'acb' paths have both finished executing i.e. after all the calls mentioned in my post. THEN i will increment to 1, and the code will go fully through the 'bac' and 'bca' paths THEN i will increment to 2 and the code will go fully through the 'cab' and 'cba' paths (answer updated)

Comment: Got it. so before anagram('acb', ''); executes, anagram('ab', 'c') ---> anagram('abc', '') has already executed and been stored in uniqueOutput? After that is all done, then you start the process of i++ at the outer level, such that anagram('' + "b", "a" + "c") ---> anagram("b", "ac"), and then you have to loop through "ac"?

Comment: Yes, thats it exactly

Comment: thanks! I am updating my question with my updated (and better) explanation attempt. I think I got it!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the second iteration.. this is the execution flow in comments:

```
    // anagram('', 'abc') level 0
      // condition false... level 0
      // first iteration: i = 0  level 0
      // anagram(a', 'bc') ( creating new execution context level 1 )
        //  condition false.. level 1
        //  iteration 1... level 1
        // anagram('ab', 'c') ( creating new execution context level 2 )
          //  condition false..  level 2
          //  iteration 1... level 2
          // anagram('abc', '') ( creating new execution context level 3 )
            // condition true.. push "abc"
          // end for of level 2 context execution
        // iteration 2...  level 1
        // anagram('ac', 'b') ( creating new execution context level 2 )
          //  condition false.. level 2
          //  iteration 1... level 2
          // anagram('acb', '') ( creating new execution context level 3 )
            // condition true.. push "abc" level 3
          // end for of level 2 execution
        // end for of level 1
      // second iteration of level 0....
      // keep this pattern till end for of level 0..
    // end anagram level 0
```

As you can see, each iteration of the level 0 is going to push 2 words to the object. If we follow your logic, each iteration is pushing just one, take into consideration that recursion is just like adding more code in that exact place, once the function call finishes the execution flow returns to the place where it was before the call of the function.

Comment: I don't follow why we are still in iteration one when you go from anagram('ab', 'c') to anagram ('abc', '')? I thought that is happening within the second iteration?

Comment: because you are in a inner level of the execution context, so in level 0 you have 3 iterations, right ? starting with 'a'.. starting with 'b', and starting with 'c', but once you are in the first iteration of level 0, there is another call to anagram, this creates another inner execution context  that’s the level 1, and for that level you also have iterations.. you need to do that iterations first than the iterations in the outer level, and the same for more inner levels as is level 2.